# Won't enter javascript if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a simple html page with javascript. I can not get my webpage to enter either of the if statements. I can get it to work on JSFiddle but not on a page from my sublime text editor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    resize this panel
    <p id="xy">

    </p>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Execute on load
        checkWidth();
        // Bind event listener
        $(window).resize(checkWidth);
      });

      function checkWidth() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        $("#xy").text("width: "+windowWidth + "   height: " + windowHeight);
        if (windowWidth >= 700 && windowWidth <= 800 && windowHeight >= 400 && windowHeight <= 500) {
          alert("dimention matched");
        }
        else {
          alert("Nope")
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Does *anything* happen? Are there errors in the console? Does your page include another `<script>` tag to import jQuery?

Comment: (There's no sign of jQuery being included in the page above.)

Comment: Can you share with us the working jsfiddle link?

Comment: Sorry I just realizes i sis not import JQuery! All is now good

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the jQuery library. Put the following script right before the `</head>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Your current code stops when it reaches this line because the dollar sign is a call to jQuery and you don't have it: $("#xy").text("width: "+windowWidth + "   height: " + windowHeight);

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend you to include the jquery.min.js which you can download on jquery.com.

Next thing, change the order of the JavaScript the function you want to use should be initialized before you use it as a short cut command NameOfFunction().

Comment: There's no need to reorder the functions.

Comment: Okay, mine didn't work once when I did that and since then I always try to keep them in that order...

Answer (score 0):

When you have added jquery, like the colleagues already mentioned, you'll still have a small problem: Every time you try to resize the window, even when it's just 1px, you run into an alert (or even multiple alerts). So even for testing following is less annoying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  resize this panel
  <p id="xy">
  </p>

  <p id="another">
  </p>

  <script>
 function checkWidth() {
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   $("#xy").text("width: "+windowWidth + "   height: " + windowHeight);
   if (windowWidth >= 700 && windowWidth <= 800 && windowHeight >= 400 && windowHeight <= 500) {
     $("#another").text("Match!");
   }
   $(window).resize(checkWidth);
 }  

$(document).ready(function() {
   // Execute on load
   checkWidth();
   // Bind event listener
   $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
    </script>
</body></html>
```